# "Half joked, half scolded" or "half-joked, half-scolded"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I'm confused because I see both [versions](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22half-joker,%20half-.%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH4sX21MLYAhUMk5QKHUiwB1kQ_AUIDygA&biw=1855&bih=990) on Google Books.

Example sentence:

> "Hey, no eavesdropping next time, you hear?" she half(-)joked, half(-) scolded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen) may help you with hyphen usage in ***compound words***.

> Hyphens are used to link words and parts of words. They are not as common today as they used to be, but there are three main cases where you should use them:
>
> **in compound words**
>
> to join prefixes to other words
>
> to show word breaks

The explanation which follows is good. Dictionaries will/may vary as to which words are hyphenated.